# Is it possible to query N:N relationships in a Dialog Query CRM Data step?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a custom entity called Department with a N:N relationship with the User entity. I have a lookup field on the Case entity for Department. I added some javascript to the onChange event of the Department field that will query the Department entity and get the users associated with it. If there is only 1 user it sets the Assigned To field on the case to that user. If there are more than one it kicks off a dialog that lets the user select which of the users associated with the Department that the case should be assigned to.

In the Dialog I'm using a Query CRM Data step to get the Users associated with a department but I can't figure out how. I thought with the N:N there would be an entry in the Related section when building the query. There are entries for Departments but they are for Created By, Modified By, and Owning User. Is it possible? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a SOAP call to retrieve all the Users associated with Department. For every N:N relationship there will be an Intersect entity and you need to identify that intersect entity name from N:N relationship in System Customization as in below fig. [Here](http://charanmandya.blogspot.in/2012/05/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-javascript.html#getTeams) I'm retrieving all the Teams associated with User. In the same way you can retrieve the Users by passing Department Id.

[image]

Note: Replace `" <q1:Operator>EqualUserId</q1:Operator>" +` with below code

```
" <q1:Operator>Equal</q1:Operator>" +
"<q1:Values>" +
"<q1:Value xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">" + _departmentId + "</q1:Value>" +
"</q1:Values>" +
```

Comment: This needs to be done from a dialog though, not from javascript.